# Internet Explorer crash on closing jQuery UI dialog due to new IE update (KB2761451)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

We are using jQuery UI Dialog to insert data into the database.  When the jQuery dialog is going to close on submit the IE hanged and showing a message: "IE stopped working".  The issue is caused due to an update "Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 9 for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2761451)". I have confirmed by uninstall this specific update the issue is resolved.

I am using following line of code to close the dialog

```
 $('#' + dialogName).dialog('close');
```

To uninstall the IE Update is not a permanent solution.
how can I fix this issue permanently ????

Comment: Is this in a `document.ready` ? And did you tried for example : `$dialog=$('#' + dialogName).dialog({close:function (){$dialog.dialog('close');}});` ?

Comment: I have this update installed and have no issue with closing jQuery dialogs. It could be some other plugin you have that trips this error.

Comment: Have you tried change jquery or jquery ui version?

Comment: have you validated you html code? i had sometimes problems with IE when there where errors. e.g. some versions of IE don't like is when you have a a self inclosing `span`  (`<span />`) or when you have block level elements inside of inline elements. in my case IE did not crash always cause of this but when corrected it didn't crash anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call .dialog() before the DOM is ready in IE.  Move your call to test() instead of $(document).ready();

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but in my case there were 3 required conditions:

1) using jquery-ui 1.10.3 (with 1.9.2 it works fine)

2) in the page's init script there were script, that adds a form to the body:

```
jQuery('<form id="frmId" method="post" action="page.aspx"></form>')
    .appendTo("body");
```

3) show modal dialog:

```
$("<div/>").dialog({modal});
```

Removing any of this condition solved this issue for me :)

And, the example at jsfiddle.net:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zm3Qm/1/

Answer (score 1):

I tracked this error down to having form elements in my dialog. Running .empty(); to clear out the contents containing the form before closing the dialog stopped IE9 from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog close before IE crash?
What happens if you lock with try catch?

```
try{
    $('#' + dialogName).dialog('close'); 
}catch(e){
    alert(e);
}
```